# Is it good to have many log filters in rsyslog conf

Tags: linux, syslog, rsyslog, logger

I am planning to add filters in rsyslog.conf to redirect the syslog messages based on a tag so that I can log using logger and redirect to a custom log file.

configuration in rsyslog.conf looks something like below,

```
:syslogtag, isequal, "xyz:" /var/log/custom/custom.log
```

Now my questions is, since there are many subsystems and scripts we might end up adding lot of filters in rsyslog.conf. will it affect the performance?

is it a good practice to use rsyslog for custom logs?

Answer (score 1):

I'm in the same boat and was only going to use compare rules on local only. the only thing i have read is to put stop after each rule.  so when a match is found it will stop checking more rules.

Now the stop method depends on your version.

newer its
stop

olderis tilde i think